# Plotting based on dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, sentiment-analysis

I am doing sentiment analysis on each chapter of a book. For every chapter, I do this:

```
chapter_n = "Every chapter is a string"
from nltk.sentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
sia.polarity_scores(chapter_n)
```

Output takes the form (neg, neu and pos add up to 1):

```
{'neg': 0.052, 'neu': 0.889, 'pos': 0.059, 'compound': 0.9998}
```

In theory, there are extremely optimistic chapters followed by sad chapters. But there are also very neutral chapters like the one above.

How could I visualise these "emotional arcs", that is, how fast it jumps from something negative to something positive?

My idea is to plot just one of these 3 points for every chapter. I was thinking of creating a new dictionary where the keys are the chapters and the values are, say, just the positive values.

```
chapters = list(D.keys())           
scores = list(D.values())      
ax.plot_date(chapters, scores, '-')
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: stacked bar plot - one for each score? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html

Comment: I would consider just making a new list of `pos` - `neg` to get the "delta" between them and plotting that simple list vs. the chapter numbers and drop `neu`.